# Fetching facebook user events using graph

Tags: graph, facebook

I am trying to write an application that uses facebook user's events as a possible data source and unfortunately I can log in and get an access token which I can use to get my picture and UID but when I try to access my events I get an empty array.

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

I am using Facebook's new Graph API but I must be doing something wrong, I tried using "perm" to get extra user permissions to access their "user_events" but that did not work at all. I am stumped any help would be greatly appreciated.

best regards!!
-ritec

Answer (score 0):

When you do the authentication bit, you'll also need to request access to the user_events extended permission.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756237/retrieving-my-own-data-via-facebook-api) has a little more info from someone in a similar position as you.

Further instructions for prompting for extended permissions can be found in the [Extended Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) documentation.